# Unity3D Shooter - How to switch to next level after all enemies get destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, counter, 2d-games

I am a newbie to Unity and I am trying to build a little shooter 2d game in C#. I am now stuck and confess that I am a little lost not knowing what the best approach is, but the problem is that my hero shoots at the enemies and they die but how do I get to the next level after the enemies are all dead? If I make a dead counter, what script do I put in? In the enemy script? Or do I make a new script but associate it with what? I also need the game to end if the hero fires his six bullets (already have a counter that makes the hero not shoot anymore after six shoots) and there are still enemies left ...
Does anyone give me some tips? Thanks!

Enemy script:

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

  public class BadguyScript : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public int maxHealth;
      public int curHealth;
      private Animator myAnimator;
      private bool isDead;
      [SerializeField]
      private float DespawnTime = 2.5f;
      [SerializeField]
      private string DeathAnimHash = "isDead"; 

      void Start()
      {
          myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
          myAnimator.enabled =true;
          myAnimator.SetBool (DeathAnimHash ,isDead);


          maxHealth = 1;
          curHealth = maxHealth;

      }
      void Update()
      {
          if (curHealth < 1)
          {
              isDead = true;
              myAnimator.SetBool (DeathAnimHash ,isDead);
              Destroy(gameObject,DespawnTime);
          }
      }
      void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
      {
          if (isDead)
             return;
          if (col.tag == "bullet")
          {
              curHealth -= 1;
              Destroy(col.gameObject);
          }
      }
  }
```

Count Bullets Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameFlow : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static float remainingShots = 6;
    public Transform shot1;
    public Transform shot2;
    public Transform shot3;
    public Transform shot4;
    public Transform shot5;
    public Transform shot6;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      if (remainingShots > 0)
      {
        shot1.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        shot1.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = false;
      }

      if (remainingShots > 1)
      {
        shot2.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        shot2.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = false;
      }

      if (remainingShots > 2)
      {
        shot3.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        shot3.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = false;
      }

      if (remainingShots > 3)
      {
        shot4.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        shot4.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = false;
      }

      if (remainingShots > 4)
      {
        shot5.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        shot5.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = false;
      }

      if (remainingShots > 5)
      {
        shot6.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        shot6.GetComponent<Image> ().enabled = false;
      }


      if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
      {
      remainingShots -= 1;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually you have somethign like a GameController (empty objet with a script), and you call some function that checks if there are still enemies remaining, each time an enemey dies. If none is remaining, change scene (or trigger the display of some "level end UI" with a button to change scene)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To switch to another scene after your conditions do the following: 
1. Add the OtherScenes to your game by doing this:

> File -> Build Settings -> Add Open Scenes

2. Do something like this in your code:

```
Enemy Script.cs

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; // Contains scene management functions

public GameObject[] enemies;

void Update()
{
    enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy"); // Checks if enemies are available with tag "Enemy". Note that you should set this to your enemies in the inspector.
    if (enemies.length == 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName"); // Load the scene with name "OtherSceneName"
    }
}

Bullet Script.cs
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

void Update()
{
    if (remainingShots == -1)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ashok kumar, thanks for your help, but now i have this error:

Assets\Scripts\EnemyScript.cs(40,23): error CS1061: 'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no accessible extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What can i do?

Comment: Its Length with a Captial letter.

Comment: Silly me...you are right...now the "out of bullets" code is working fine (the game switch to the fail scene when all bullets are fired) but didn`t work when all the enemies were dead...i think i tag them correctly.........well, now i have to work but tonight i will look better for the problem .

thank you again, Ashok

Comment: In the inspector, in the enemy object, i have to change the size parameter of Enemies?

Answer (score -1):

use an empty `gameobject` and attach this line of code in update method .

```
if (enemies.length == 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName"); // Load the scene with name "OtherSceneName"
    }
```

As you were using the enemy script and when all the enemies dies then there is no `gameobject` which hold the script.

Comment: These details are already provided in the accepted answer and do not add anything new to the post.  Please consider adding more to your answer or deleting it.